# Copy Azure Append Blob getting a 404

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

Trying to move a append blob to another container after processing it.
I am first just trying to copy it, then I will delete it (unless there is a actual move function?)

Using C#

I keep getting a 404
: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. ---> System.Net.WebException : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

I have tried creating a SasToken at both the container and blob level.

```
private static void  copyBlob(messageClass msgPassed, CloudStorageAccount storageAccount)
    {
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer sourceContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(receiveScanContainer);

        //create a SAS on source blob container with "read" permission. We will append this SAS later
        var sasToken = sourceContainer.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
        {
            Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read,
            SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
        });

        CloudBlobContainer targetContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(archiveContainer);

        CloudAppendBlob sourceBlob = sourceContainer.GetAppendBlobReference(msgPassed.currentName);
        var sasToken2 = sourceBlob.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
        {
            Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read,
            SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1),

        });

       CloudAppendBlob targetBlob = targetContainer.GetAppendBlobReference(msgPassed.currentName);
        string name = sourceBlob.Uri.Segments.Last();
       CloudAppendBlob destBlob = targetContainer.GetAppendBlobReference(name+sasToken2);

        targetBlob.StartCopy(destBlob);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK...dug into it more.
The below works.
I also was passing the name of the target container slightly wrong (one letter off) from what the container name actually was.

```
    private static void  copyBlob(messageClass msgPassed, CloudStorageAccount storageAccount)
    {


        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer sourceContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(receiveScanContainer);

        CloudBlobContainer targetContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(archiveContainer);

        CloudAppendBlob sourceBlob = sourceContainer.GetAppendBlobReference(msgPassed.currentName);
        CloudAppendBlob targetBlob = targetContainer.GetAppendBlobReference(msgPassed.currentName);


        targetBlob.StartCopy(sourceBlob);
    }
```

Comment: No, you should not have to do this. I think the problem is with the way you're creating an instance of CloudAppendBlob for destination (destBlob).

Comment: Your right....strange.  Removing the CreateOrReplace and it still works.  I found what I was doing wrong and updated the answer.  One letter off on a name.

Comment: That will work because you're copying blob from one container to another container in same storage account. For copying across storage accounts, you would need to either make blob publicly accessible or use a SAS Token.